# Problema con formulario ajax

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, web

Estoy aprendiendo a usar `ajax` al hacer `click` en el botón del envió del formulario no hace nada.

Pongo mi código:

```js
// Esta es mi función:
$("#virgen").click(function virgen() {
consulta = $("#virgen").val();
$.ajax({
  data: 'b=' + consulta,
  type: "POST",
  url: "servidor.php",
  success: function(data) { // es el parametro que te devuelve
    var variable = JSON.parse(data);
    lat1 = variable.lat1;
    lng1 = variable.lng1;
  }
})
map.removeMarker(markers[0]);
markers[0] = map.addMarker({
  lat: lat1,
  lng: lng1
}); // pone marcador en mapa

enlazarMarcador(s);
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="virgen" value="CIFP Virgen de gracia" class="boton" onclick="virgen()">
```

He comprobado que están todas las librerías importadas

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando en jquery se efectúa $('#idButton').click atacha el evento click al botón automáticamente no siendo necesario tanto la declaración del nombre de la función como el evento onclick en el botón.

Además he quitado un cierre de paréntesis ")" que sobraba.

```js
$("#virgen").click(function () {
    consulta = $("#virgen").val();
    $.ajax({
        data: 'b=' + consulta,
        type: "POST",
        url: "servidor.php",
        success: function (data) { // es el parametro que te devuelve
            var variable = JSON.parse(data);
            lat1 = variable.lat1;
            lng1 = variable.lng1;
        }
    })
    map.removeMarker(markers[0]);
    markers[0] = map.addMarker({ lat: lat1, lng: lng1 });  // pone marcador en mapa

    enlazarMarcador(s);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="virgen" value="CIFP Virgen de gracia" class="boton">
```

Aprovecho para comentarte que al crear la función dentro del evento click de jquery lo que estas creando es una función en otro contexto no visualizable desde fuera del contexto (desde fuera del evento).